# How to parse child elements of XML-object with Linq

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I am trying to parse this document. Here is a part of it:

```
<JobPortalPositionList>
    <CustomerAlias>Frogn</CustomerAlias>
    <CustomerName>Frogn kommune</CustomerName>
    <TransactionStatus>
        <Description>The operation completed successfully.</Description>
        <StatusCode>Success</StatusCode>
    </TransactionStatus>
    <Items>
        <JobPortalPosition>
            <CustomerAlias>Frogn</CustomerAlias>
            <CustomerName>Frogn kommune</CustomerName>
            <TransactionStatus>
```

The url:  http://api.hr-manager.net/JobPortal.svc/frogn/positionlist/xml/
My try with Linq:

```cs
string uri="http://api.hr-manager.net/JobPortal.svc/frogn/positionlist/xml/";
XElement xmlJobTree = XElement.Load(uri);

var listOfJobpositions =
    (from jobpositions in xmlJobTree.Elements("JobPortalPositionList")
                                    .Elements("Items")
                                    .Elements("JobPortalPosition")
    select jobpositions).ToList();
```

I get an empty list. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of problems with your code.  The document has a namespace which your code doesn't account for.

The root of the document is:

```
<JobPortalPositionList xmlns="http://schemas.hr-manager.net/jobportal/1.0/"
                       xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
```

Since the default namespace is `http://schemas.hr-manager.net/jobportal/1.0/`, your queries need to use them.

```
XNamespace ns = "http://schemas.hr-manager.net/jobportal/1.0/";
var listOfJobpositions =
    (from jobpositions in xmlJobTree.Elements(ns + "JobPortalPositionList")
                                    .Elements(ns + "Items")
                                    .Elements(ns + "JobPortalPosition")
    select jobpositions).ToList();
```

Sidenote, that could be rewritten to simply:

```
var listOfJobpositions =
    xmlJobTree.Elements(ns + "JobPortalPositionList")
              .Elements(ns + "Items")
              .Elements(ns + "JobPortalPosition")
              .ToList();
```

Secondly, you parsed the document as an `XElement`.  So the parsed element `xmlJobTree` will refer to the root node of the document, not the document itself.  So the first part of your query is checking to see if `JobPortalPositionList` is an element of the `JobPortalPositionList` element.  That's a definite no so it yields nothing.

You should *always* parse a complete XML document as an `XDocument` so you don't confuse yourself here.  As an `XDocument`, queries will be relative to the document, not the root.  And everything else will just work.

```
var xmlJobTree = XDocument.Load(uri);
```

Answer (score -1):

you can to do something like:

```
var documents =
    (from docs in documentRoot.Descendants("document")
     select new
     {
         Id = (string) docs.Attribute("id"),
         Sections = docs.Elements("section")
     }).ToList();

foreach (var doc in documents)
{
    foreach (var section in doc.Sections)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("SectionId: " + section.Attribute("id"));
        foreach (var item in section.Elements("item"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ItemId: " + item.Attribute("id"));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can read xml document like this :- XElement documentRoot = XElement.Load("document.xml"); var documents = (from docs in documentRoot.Descendants("document") select new { Id = (string) docs.Attribute("id"), Sections = docs.Elements("section"), Items = docs.Elements("section").Elements("item") }).ToList();